# Change my url so that it doesnt show my data but i have a GET method how can i do that without rewriting everything into a post method? PHP

Tags: php

So i started a Project and im new to php so i did a GET method so that i can fetch data from the url but now all my data shows up in the url and i want to change the url so that it doesnt show all my data because i dont want the user using the website to see the ID i have in my Database is there a way to do it or do i have to rewrite everything in a post method ? because im search alot and i didnt find anything usefull. if i have to rewrite it to post methode i would like some help thanks.

Comment: You have to change method and rewrite all GETs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my friend. There's no way around it, you'll just have to switch it to post

Comment: hmm thanks man is there anywhere where i can learn about it or read about how to work with post ?

Comment: Yes, lots. W3 schools website is great for beginners (www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). But the processing works very similarly to $_GET, so as long as you've got that down, I'd imagine it won't take you long to work out how to $_POST. Good luck!

Comment: thanks man! my problem is that i have everything in a link and i dont know another way to get to the specific user data without a link.

Comment: so then to switch using post, you would have to do something like...

`<form method="post" action="/which-ever-page-you-want-to-post-to">
<input type="hidden" value="id-value" name="an-appropriate-name"/>
<button>Go to the page</button>
</form>`

...and then on the other side. Switch the `$_GET` for `$_POST`. Hope that makes sense. If not, I'd highly suggest doing some more research through W3 Schools website (or somewhere else if you're not a fan of this).

Comment: thanks, im going to try it if not im gonna do more research :)

Comment: All the best :)